# Having a hard time using flowtype.js to make my text more responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, jquery-plugins

I've been trying to make the text in my wesbite more responsive and I've been trying to use flowtype.js seen here: http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/ to accomplish this. However no matter what I do it doesn't seem to be working. The text does not resize itself when the viewport is changed I've included my code and a jfiddle down below. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4jy1dvxx/

Html:

```
                    <div id="whoText">

                        <p class="header">Who we are</p>

                        <p class="boxText">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>

                        <p class="boxText">
        Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Lati</p>

                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#whoText {
    width:45%;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
}

#whatText {
    width:45%;
    float:right;
    height:500px;
}

#whiteBox {
    width:30%;
    float:right;
    height:500px;
}

#textContain {
    width:60%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.header {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    font-size:1.875em;
    font-weight:800;   
    text-align:left;
    color:#000;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}

.boxText {
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size:1.063em;
    color:#000;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:23px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
```

JS:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('whoText').flowtype({
                minimum   : 500,
                maximum   : 1200
            });
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

Your missing the hashtag used for targeting the ID whoText.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#whoText').flowtype({
            minimum   : 500,
            maximum   : 1200
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the selector to `body` instead of `whoText`, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').flowtype({
            minimum   : 500,
            maximum   : 1200});
 })
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/ue1vano0/4/)

Comment: Thanks @lpg that worked! However I was wondering if it's possible to target specific elements besides body